# how to force date and time to be permanently shown on lock screen?

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen, time, clock

Ubuntu 20.04 here.

I searched here but found nothing: https://extensions.gnome.org/# (may be I didn't search well?)

If I keep pressing ESC, it will toggle user login and the date&time.
I need it to be shown all the time and not toggle as I read notifications that have time related info.
By "all the time" i mean only while i am pressing keys (i keep hitting ctrl key to keep the screen on).

Alternatively, **the date&time that already shows on the top panel (when it is unlocked) could just be allowed to show on the lock screen** (just had this idea, will research).

Comment: In the interests of saving electricity they intentionally designed a black screen. You can install a different screen saver though.

Comment: Oh, by "all the time" i mean only while i am pressing keys (i keep hitting ctrl key to keep the screen on)